# Verifying integrability of $I = \int_{0}^{2}dx\int_{0}^{4-x^{2}}\left(\frac{xe^{2y}}{4-y}\right)dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral

I want to calculate the following integral : 
$$I = \int_{0}^{2}dx\int_{0}^{4-x^{2}}\left(\frac{xe^{2y}}{4-y}\right)dy$$
I am not sure whether this can be calculated as it is, but my reasoning was the following in order to simplify the calculation: Make this a double integral, change the order of integration while at the same time using Tonneli and Fubini to verify the existence of the integral and calculate. I managed to do that and my result is numerically correct.

However, in order to use Tonneli-Fubini, calculate the integral using the opposite order I first have to verify it exists ( so I don't get a different result form the opposite order ).

Here is my problem. From what I can see:
$$f(y) = \frac{xe^{2y}}{4-y}\epsilon C_{0}[0, 4[$$
Which is tto say I have to verify integrability when $y = 4$. But:
$$\frac{1}{y-4} = O\left(f(y)\right), y\rightarrow 4$$
which by the integrability criteria means the function is not integrable when $y = 4$.

I know I have to be doing something wrong, but I don't seem to be able to find what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=x^2$.  Then the integral becomes $\frac{1}{2}\int_{u=0}^4 \int_{y=0}^{4-u} \frac{e^{2y}}{4-y}dy$.  Change the order of integration to get $\frac{1}{2}\int_{y=0}^4 \frac{e^{2y}}{4-y}dy\int_{u=0}^{4-y}du=\frac{1}{2}\int_{y=0}^4 e^{2y}dy= (e^8-1)/4$.

Comment: My problem was not solving the integral, but verifying that it exists. If you don't do that, it is possible that one order of integration has a meaning but gives a different result than the original one.

Comment: You are correct.  However, dominant convergence theorem will work.  Since $e^{2y}$ is bounded, the integrand is dominated by $\frac{M}{4-y}$.  The integral is dominated by $\int_{x=0}^2xdx\int_{y=0}^{4-x^2}\frac{M}{4-y}dy=M\int_{x=0}^2 x(-ln(x^2))dx$, which is finite.

Comment: I am going to justify a little differently, but that helped a lot, thanks :)